# java getRuntime().exec() does not work for running basic cmd commands

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to run cmd commands using getRuntime().exec(). The problem is that it works only if my command string is ***ipconfig***, whereas if I try to run commands like ***java -version*** or ***time***, it then throws the error :

*java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "time": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified*

```
   String command = "time";
    Process p;
    try {
         p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
         BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         String line;
            while (true) {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line == null) { break; }
                //System.out.println(line);
                textField_1.setText(line);
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: *The system cannot find the file specified* so maybe not on your path?

Comment: Does "time" command work in your `cmd`?

Comment: Because the folder that contains the java program is not in your environment path. Add it in the path or specify the absolute path of the java command. You could value a property at runtime instead of hardcoding it in your code.

Comment: @SanketMakani Yes, it does! All the commands like java -version, date, etc., works!

Comment: @davidxxx I tried, but still get the same error! I added my folder in the environment path.

Comment: I can't say why `java` isn't found, but normally `time` and `date` are internal commands of the cmd shell, so you would need to run them as `cmd.exe /c time`, etc.

Comment: are you running the program from eclipse(IDE) or from command line?

Comment: @eryksun I have tried this method also. The problem with this is that my jFrame doesn't show anything when I try this. All the content including jLabels and text-fields gets disappeared.

Comment: @Bhavesh I am running my program from eclipse IDE.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have added my folder to the environment path. Have also tried to enter `cmd.exe /c time` as my command string. Still not working?

Comment: @Pravar, sorry, I haven't used Java in a while and didn't realize that it's running the command without a console and all standard handles redirected to pipes. So the bare `time` command would be blocked waiting for a new system time to be written to stdin. Try `cmd.exe /c "time /t"` instead.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you so much! You are great! Now the `time` and `date` commands work fine! But these were just some examples I gave. Do you know how to run other commands? I need to get the version of CPU and its speed, so the command is `wmic cpu get name,CurrentClockSpeed,MaxClockSpeed` ! This command doesn't work as well!

Comment: I actually solved this issue by using **ProcessBuilder**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by using `ProcessBuilder`. I still don't know why the earlier code didn't work for all the commands. But by using `ProcessBuilder`, I was able to perform any `cmd`query.

Here's the code for reference:

```
String command_ping = "ping " + host_name;

            try {

                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command_ping);
                builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process p = builder.start();

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while (true) 
                {

                    buffer.append(line).append("\n");
                    line = r.readLine();
                    if (line == null) { break; }
                }
                message_ping= buffer.toString();
                p.waitFor();
                r.close();

            } 

            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: In the shell you can use where.exe to determine what's an internal command and what's external. ping.exe is external, so you really shouldn't use the shell to execute it, especially if the `host_name` string comes from user input or an untrusted source. It's easily exploitable.